# REACT-NATIVE Task :expo-modules-core:externalNativeBuildCleanRelease FAILED

Tags: react-native, apk, gradlew, eofexception, expo-module

I am a newbie to React Native. I was trying to build an APK in my project. I was successfully able to make APKs before in the current project. But recently I started getting the following error. I have no idea why or what is causing this. I even tried the whole process from the scratch but this error still persists. Please Help !!!

```
> Task :expo-modules-core:externalNativeBuildCleanRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:externalNativeBuildCleanRelease'.
> java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I am following these steps for generating my APK: [Link](https://www.doabledanny.com/react-native-signed-APK)

When I run `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease` generally it used to execute the build and after successful build I get my APK. But this time I got the above Error.

When I tried running just `./gradlw clean` the error still persists. So I know that the error is in that part but I have no Idea of why and What is causing it.